# Google PUB/SUB publish message over C socket connection

Tags: sockets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to find a way to connect Google pubsub directly over a socket connection written in C language. Is their a way to do that? I will be publishing JSON and/or Binary messages over the socket. Is their a specific message format that needs to be followed.

Comment: In order to understand better your case, can you give an overview of your process? Such as which tool you will be connecting to Pub/Sub through C Socket connection and where  the published messages will come from.

Comment: Hey @AlexandreMoraes, thanks for taking your time on this. My source is IBM mainframe system and we have some tty messages that needs to be sent to GCP. Looking at the volume(more than 20k TPS), we decided to look for a socket based solution instead of HTTP based as it will minimize  the overhead.